# pyton outlook inconsistency with execution

Tags: python, winapi, outlook, pywin32, office-automation

My issue is allocating emails to folders. When I allocate by subject (see code below) it works fine.

```
example_mail = [message for message in inbox.Items if 'example' in message.Subject]
for message in example_mail:
    if message.UnRead == True:
        message.Move(example_folder)
```

However, when I do the same method for allocating by email address (see code below), it will either only move a couple emails (and take extremely long for the quantity delivered) or just not seem to execute at all with no errors.

```
example_mail1 = [message for message in inbox.Items if 'sender@example.com' in message.SenderEmailAddress]
for message in example_mail1:
    if message.UnRead == True:
        message.Move(example_folder1)
```

Both methods are the same in terms of code and approach, although for some reason the outcomes are completely different. I'm using: win32, a shared email inbox (work) and a company laptop.

I have also tried the subject script on a much higher quantity to see if the problem lied within the amount of emails found when using the email address script, but even with a very small amount of emails i still get the same problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You sure message is unread? also should be  `if message.UnRead:` , remove == true [recommendations](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if 'sender@example.com' in message.SenderEmailAddress

There could be multiple factors such as case sensitivity and etc. Moreover, iterating over all items in the folder is not really a good idea:

```
example_mail1 = [message for message in inbox.Items if 'sender@example.com' in message.SenderEmailAddress]
```

Plus after that code you check the `UnRead` property which is not efficient.

Instead, I'd recommend using the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class from the Outlook object model instead. So, you will get only items that correspond to your conditions.

Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

For example, you could set up the following search criteria:

```
Filter = "@SQL=" & "urn:schemas:httpmail:senderemail Like '%sender@example.com%'"
```

Comment: Okay thank you, how would I write that line of code using Items.Find method?

Comment: You just need to pass the filter string to the `Find` or `Restrict` method. Have you read the articles mentioned above?

Comment: I'm having problems understanding it as it's in C# not python, unless it works similarly? my problem is incorporating the find method to the email folder. If i use it on a simple list i create then its fine, but I don't know how to use it in accordance with the chosen email folder. If that makes sense?

Comment: The Outlook object model is common for all kind of applications. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Just spent some time trying to refine the code, the below code works now, any suggestions for refining/ improvements? I thought it'd be best to use .Restrict as apparently it's better to use that for larger data than the .Find.

Comment: Correctly. Do you get the right results now?

Comment: `job_ads = inbox.Items` (next line) `jobads = job_ads.Restrict("[SenderEmailAddress] = 'jobalerts-noreply@linkedin.com'")` (next line) `for message in jobads:` (next line) `message.Move(sub_folder)`